# R package dev: should I make data files internal or external?

Tags: r, package, devtools

(Trying again with this question to make it more clear.)

I am attempting to write a package that makes it easier to access data from a web API, and deciding whether to make lookup tables and query defaults internal or external data, as outlined in the [Data chapter](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html) of *R Packages*.

As I understand, there are drawbacks to each.  Internal data is meant for data only used by the package, invisible to users. It is added to the package with `devtools::use_data(x, mtcars, internal = TRUE)` which adds `sysdata.rda` to the `R/` package folder. However, although the package "needs" the data tables, I also want my data to be visible to the users, so they can correct errors, and perhaps add additional data files by pull request to extend the capability of the package. Furthermore, since I'm dealing with multiple files, not all available at the moment, rebundling everything into `R/sysdata.rda` every time there's a change seems inconvenient.

An alternative would be to make the lookup tables and query defaults external data, which is added with the default `internal = FALSE` flag: `devtools::use_data(x, mtcars)`, adding `mtcars.rda` to the `data/` package folder. The advantage is that such data is clearly visible to the user, but the downside is that I don't know how to access it from within the package functions without getting an error when running `devtools::check()`: `object 'querydefaults' not found`. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: There are packages like [nycflights13](https://github.com/hadley/nycflights13) that provide lazy loaded data to users. Is that the paradigm you want to follow? If so, check out their package structure on github. Your question doesn't make it clear exactly what the requirements are.

Comment: That package is all external data according to the definitions [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html#data); there are no internal functions which access those datasets.  I want to be able to provide data as nycflights does, but also have functions that use the data.

Comment: Is there something that's preventing that? How are you trying to use these data frames in your package?

Comment: I'm refering to them by name: `x <- lookuptable`  It works. The problem is that I get an error when I run `devtools::check()`. I can ignore that but not a good idea as it probably means I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the dataset both as external and internal, and it resolves the issue with `devtools::check()`. See [the RIC package](https://github.com/aminadibi/RIC) as an example.